# How to use WCF RIA Services in PRISM 4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, prism-4

I am developing Silverlight application with Prism 4 and WCF RIA service.
I had searched on google to get sample explaining this, but failed to get any successful output.

I am confuse about how to use RIA service in PRISM Application.

Please suggest any link which provide sample for this.
Help me.

Comment: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-4-Integrating-with-the-Model-View-ViewModel-Pattern.aspx

Comment: Thanks  rahularyansharma. But this site does not explain how to use RIA Service in PRISM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WCF RIA and PRISM 4 to develop a Silverlight application. Each of the technologies is targeted at a different part of your application.

WCF RIA services provides you with the tools to communicate from client to server to persist your data.

PRISM4 is designed to allow you to construct modular well architected Silverlight (and WPF) applications.

I have a large LOB application built using this approach. I use PRISM4 modularity to load modules into my application. The viewmodels in each of the modules connect to WCF RIA domain service contexts to get and modify data.

I'd recommend looking at Nikhilk's Book Club sample application for the RIA side http://www.nikhilk.net/RIA-Services-MIX10-Slides-Code.aspx.